# using container-fluid within bootstrap cause horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-system

Here is a simple example:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">DUMMY CONTENT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### [Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/p23EB/1/)

When I see the result in browser I get a horizontal scrollbar.

Why is this happening?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`container-fluid` was originally taken out of Bootstrap 3.0, but [**added back in 3.1.1**](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/6273604601c58284f49b38ae4e52533b9689437c)

To fix this, you can *either*:

1. Use the [newer version of Bootstrap style sheet](http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css)

   #### [Demo with New Style Sheet in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/p23EB/7/)
2. Or add in the class yourself

   The `.row` adds a `15px` margin to the left and right.  Since `.container-fluid` fills up `100%` of the screen width, the extra margin space causes overflow issues.

   To fix this, you need to add padding to `.container-fluid` class

   ```css
   .container-fluid {
       padding-right: 15px;
       padding-left: 15px;
       margin-right: auto;
       margin-left: auto;
   }
   ```

   #### [Demo with Custom container class in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/p23EB/8/)

Comment: Updating bootstrap (from 3.0.0 to 3.3.7) was the easiest approach for me. Worked like a charm!

Comment: The `auto` margins are not necessary.

Answer (score 48):

I also faced this problem. I don't know the cause of the problem. It maybe a bug from `Twitter Bootstrap`. Now, I have to manually add the `overflow-x:hidden` to my `body` tag:

```
body { 
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lvarayut/p23EB/2/)

Comment: Lvarayut, interesting workaround.  The real problem is that Bootstrap v3.0 doesn't include `.container-fluid` at all!  Open up your console and see how many matched rules appear or Ctrl + F through the stylesheet.  The easiest fix is to just grab the newest style sheet for version 3.1

Comment: This solution is very nice, thanks!

Strangely enough adding 5px margin left and right on the body did the same for me while still let the website comopnents 'touch' the edges of the canvas completely (using 24 columns with 15px gutter)

Comment: You should note that this workaround only hides the scrollbar and your layout can still be "moved left and right". This becomes a problem if your target devices is a tablet or mobile and so your page visitors move your site to the left while scrolling down. Imho a bad user experience ;)

Comment: Many thanks for this! For mobile I also had to add overflow-x: hidden; to html {} as well.

Answer (score 14):

In my case this fix worked well:

```
.row {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
.row{
margin: 0px;
}
```

quick easy fix this is all you need

Comment: You made my day! <3

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to encapsulate your row classes with containers.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        text
    </div>
</div>
```

The container offsets the `-15` margins on rows with `+15`.

Comment: This answer causes the page not to be full width.. thats the idea if you're using fluid isn't it?

Comment: I found adding my rows within a container-fluid did the trick

Answer (score 3):

You can dirty hack the row by add new class to the full width row and create overwrite css file:

```css
.noLRMar{
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row noLRMar">
  
 </div>
```

Comment: [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/#notation) has the built-in `mx-0` class that does exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

**Bootstrap 5 solution:**

You can add to the `.container-fluid` element a second class `.overflow-hidden`.

Comment: This was the right answer for me :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, changing `@grid-gutter-width` to odd number caused this, because;

`mixins/grid.less`

```
.container-fixed(@gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left:  floor((@gutter / 2));
  padding-right: ceil((@gutter / 2));
  &:extend(.clearfix all);
}
```

So if you pick an odd `gutter-width` then you will end up having uneven paddings and you will see a horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem, using .container-fluid on its own creates horizontal scrolling, but I fixed it with a nested .container, hope that helps!

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are repeating an answer which was already given several times, and which is **wrong**. The whole point of using `.container-fluid` is to have the `.row` expand the entire width of the viewport. Wrapping `.row` in a `.container` defeats the purpose of using `.container-fluid`. Also, the problem can be fixed by setting left and right padding of `15px` on `.container-fluid` (to counter `.row`'s negative margins) or by upgrading Bootstrap from `v3.0` to `v3.3.7` (which contains the padding fix). As a side node, the auto margins are not required in this case.

Answer (score -2):

With Bootstrap 3.3.5, I was getting a horizontal scroll bar at certain widths near the change from the medium (md) to small (sm) screen size. Adding a `div.row` between my `div.container-fluid` and `div.container` fixed it for me.

```
<div class="container-fluid  myFullWidthStylingClass">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    #content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Adding `margin:0;` to your rows will break some styling elements.

Comment: This is incorrect. According to bootstrap documentation, only columns should be direct children of row. And rows can't be children of another row.

From Bootstrap's documentation: "Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows."

Answer (score -2):

Set **max-width** in the container class instead of width. It will remove the horizontal bar.

```
.container-fluid { 
    border:1px solid red;
    max-width:1349px;
    min-height:1356px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px; 
}
```

Comment: this doens't make sense. you're using .container-fluid becouse you don't want to have a max-width.